# How I can put a label above the button in android studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, button, label, android-constraintlayout

I want to design a messages button that is attached to a label showing the number of messgaes. Like the image below

[image]

I designed it with android studio, but the label is not aligned properly. How I can put it at the top of the button?

[image]

Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout    
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/msg"
        android:layout_width="157dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:background="@color/lightgrey"
        android:backgroundTint="#@color/lightgrey"
        android:text="Messages"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.206" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mark"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_textview"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2"
        android:textColor="@color/lightgrey"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.662"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.17" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove any constraints of the `TextView` attached to the parent, and make the `TextView` only constrained to the `Button`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/msg"
        android:layout_width="157dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:background="@color/lightgrey"
        android:backgroundTint="#@color/lightgrey"
        android:text="Messages"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.206"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mark"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_textview"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2"
        android:textColor="@color/lightgrey"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/msg"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/msg"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/msg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/msg" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Preview

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [BadgeDrawable](https://material.io/develop/android/components/badging).

```
val badge = BadgeDrawable.create(this)
BadgeUtils.attachBadgeDrawable(badge, yourButton)
// usage
badge.number = 5
```

Comment: I did some research about this notification badges thing, looks professional, but a little bit complex. Thank you so much for your informative answer 